# No Google Drive API writersCanInvite equivalent?

Tags: permissions, migration

With Docs API deprecated and some nice new functionality in Drive API, I'm working on updating some of my file migration scripts. However, I've found there doesn't seem to be a Drive API equivalent to the writersCanInvite parameter in Docs API v3. Being able to set this attribute on a file would be extremely important during migration scenarios as without it, the migrated file would be left open to having editors share it out further.

Not having writersCanInvite avaialble in addition to not being able to see email addresses (or some Unique ID) for the ACLs is preventing me from fully porting over my migration script to Drive API v2.

Thanks Guys,

Jay

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we now have a writersCanShare attribute that controls this:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

at the moment, it's not marked as writeable but I had no problems making it False for a new document so I'm guessing that's just a documenation issue.